# How to make UISearchController show and hide itself when button pressed?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, uinavigationitem

I just read a bit on how to use `UISearchController`s, and I want to figure out how I can make it show up with the click of a button, and make it disappear fully when the cancel button is pressed.

Here is my function.

```
@IBAction func searchPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Event Name"
    
    
}
```

When you first log in, you see the magnifying glass image and when I click it, this happens.
[image: Result]

The green separator appears, and I have to scroll down to see the search bar. What I want to do is for when the button is pressed, it automatically drops down the `UISearchBar` and makes it focused with a floating cursor, and when the user presses cancel it goes back into hiding until the magnifying glass button is pressed again.

Comment: The answer has already been answered here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38729151/show-search-bar-with-action-bar-item

Comment: Thanks  @Damien